# Adding multiple the samve views

Tags: xcode, view, foreach, addsubview

I searched the net and books, for an answer but didn't find it. (maybe because I searched the wrong way, or everyone knew the answer to it, except me)

So my problem is like this: 
I have a view (made in Interface builder) because I know I will need more views that looks the same. I know how to add 1 view, (or more), but the problem is, I don't know how much products there will be in the database. 
So for each product, I would need to add another view, with different data. 
The only problem now, How can I add those multiple views?

If there would always be 5 products, I could just do it like this:

```
ProductController *productfirstController;
ProductController *productsecondController;
...
[scrollview addSubview:productfirstController.view];
[scrollview addSubview:productsecondController.view];
...
```

But like you see, this it's a horrible way of programming.

My first thought was if I could use a string like this: 
(the iInt is an integer in a for lus, on the end it add up with 1)

```
NSString *productController = "productController%d',iInt;
```

But here I couldn't get further.

does someone has an idea how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using individual variables for the views, use an `NSArray`. Use a loop to add them to the `NSArray` and `scrollview`. Here it is in detail:

```
NSArray *productViews = [[NSArray alloc] init];

ProductController *productController;
for (...) {
    productController = [[ProductController alloc] init...];

    [scrollview addSubview:productfirstController.view];
    [productViews addObject:productfirstController];
    [productController release];
}
```

Comment: I found the answer, Thanks for the help! I had to make the productcontroller as an array: example: ProductController *productController[5]; and when I added it to my subview I had to do it like this: [self addSubview:productController[i]];